# Java - access to variable within inner class or assign a value to final variable

Tags: java, inner-classes, final

I need to create several buttons and upload files. So I want to create a function to set these buttons. However, I'm getting a compilation error inside of my `setNewButton`.

My code is shown as below:

```java
public class Solution extends JFrame {
    private static final String FILE_NAME_1 = "my file1";
    private File file1;
    private void setNewButton(Container contentPane, final String fileName, String format, File file) {
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        final Label label = new Label("Select " + fileName + " in ." + format +" format");
        contentPane.add(label);
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        Button selection = new Button("Select " + fileName);
        contentPane.add(selection);
        selection.addActionListener(new FileSelectionListener("Only " + format + " is allowed", format) {
            @Override
            protected void setSelection(File selectedFile) {
                file = selectedFile;  // compilation error here
                label.setText("Selected" + fileName + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        });
    }

    public uploadFiles() {
        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        setNewButton(contentPane, FILE_NAME_1, "xls", file1);
    }
}
```

The error is: `Variable file is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final`

I have checked some similar questions in stackoverflow. I know `file` has to be final like `label` and `fileName` here.

However `file` here could be `final` since I would like to assign `selectedFile` to it.

I would like to know if there is any walkaround for this problem.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Thanks to @M. Prokhorov and @Chang Liu.
According to  [JLS 8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be effectively final, or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

So when I tried to send a parameter `file` inside `FileSlectionListener`, there will be a compile error. However, the member `file1` inside Solution is not local variable, so if I delete the `file` from my method, there will be no error. So @talex 's anwser is right in this case.

However since my problem is to find a method to pass a `File` to inner class and assign the variable with `selectedFile`, I couldn't find a way for it. My workaround is based on @Chang Liu's answer.

My revised code is as below:

```java
public class Solution extends JFrame {
    private static final String FILE_NAME_1 = "my file1";
    private File file1;
    private void setNewButton(Container contentPane, final String fileName, String format) {
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        final Label label = new Label("Select " + fileName + " in ." + format +" format");
        contentPane.add(label);
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        Button selection = new Button("Select " + fileName);
        contentPane.add(selection);
        selection.addActionListener(new FileSelectionListener("Only " + format + " is allowed", format) {
            @Override
            protected void setSelection(File selectedFile) {
                setFile(selectedFile, fileName);  // no compilation error here
                label.setText("Selected" + fileName + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        });
    }

    public uploadFiles() {
        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        setNewButton(contentPane, FILE_NAME_1, "xls", file1);
    }

    private void setFile(File file, String fileName) {
        switch (fileName) {
            case FILE_NAME_1:
                sollFile = file;
                break;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError("Unknown File");
        }
    }
}
```

Still, welcome to give me any advise if you have a better answer. :)

Comment: I'm looking for where `selectedFile` is declared.  Where is that?

Comment: @markspace It's a parameter to the setSelection method.

Comment: See [this JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) about your error. What it basically comes down to - java strongly forbids (via compile error) anonymous inner classes (including lambdas) from "capturing" variables that might be reassigned while the inner class instance is active.

Comment: Thank you @M.Prokhorov It helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated from [M. Prokhorov's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910048/java-access-to-variable-within-inner-class-or-assign-a-value-to-final-variable?noredirect=1#comment76797324_44910048), if you go to the [JLS 8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3), you will see it is stated that:

> *Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be [effectively final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.*
>
> *Similar rules on variable use apply in the body of a lambda expression.*

So the parameter `File file` of method `setNewButton` as a variable is not *[effectively final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)* in your inner class `new FileSelectionListener`'s method `setSelection`, i.e., you assigned a new value to this variable, which makes it **not** *effectively final*.

Some workaround to resolve this compile-time error, by defining a setter for `file` instead of passing an argument (but I am not sure whether this is a best practice):

```
public class Solution extends JFrame {
    private static final String FILE_NAME_1 = "Selected SOLL:";
    private File file;
    private void setNewButton(Container contentPane, final String fileName, String format) {
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        final Label label = new Label("Select " + fileName + " in ." + format +" format");
        contentPane.add(label);
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        Button selection = new Button("Select " + fileName);
        contentPane.add(selection);
        selection.addActionListener(new FileSelectionListener("Only " + format + " is allowed", format) {
            @Override
            protected void setSelection(File selectedFile) {
                setFile(selectedFile);  // call file setter here
                label.setText("Selected" + fileName + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        });
    }

    // define a setter for your File member
    private void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void uploadFiles() {
        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        setNewButton(contentPane, FILE_NAME_1, "xls");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two variables with name `file`. One is class variable and another is method parameter.

Just remove parameter `file` from your method and all will work fine.

Comment: No it won't, see my comment on the question.

Comment: I was just typing this up. This is ABSOLUTELY the correct answer! Change the name of the method parameter to something other than "file" and the compile warning goes away.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov you are rigt about JLS, but wrong in this particular case. That rule do not apply to instance variables.

Comment: @talex, he has method argument that shadows instance variable, and he doesn't use `this.Solution.file`, so compiler assumes he tries to access method argument, making it not final. Instance variables get away with this because actual access looks like `this.<class>.<name>`, so the variable that should be considered if it's final is `this`, which is a pretty safe bet as far as that check is concerned.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes. This is why I suggest to remove parameter.

Comment: @talex In my code, I have different name for the `private File file;`

Comment: This is not the reason why the compile error happened.

Comment: @talex I think I understand your answer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create yourself a mutable wrapper class for the file:

```
public class FileWrapper {

    /** The file. */
    private File file;

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Then you can use a final instance of that class:

```
final private FileWrapper fileWrapper = new FileWrapper();

// ...     

selection.addActionListener(new FileSelectionListener("Only " + format + " is allowed", format) {
        @Override
        protected void setSelection(File selectedFile) {
            fileWrapper.setFile(selectedFile);  
            label.setText("Selected" + fileName + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });
```

And get the last selected file by calling `fileWrapper.getFile()` outside of your inner class.

Comment: You may want to wrap `file` in an `AtomicReference` to guarantee thread-safety.

Comment: To make this answer complete, would be good to explain why this error occured in the first place.

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS I like your answer. However, there will be a problem. `setSelection` will not work util I click the button. However, if I call `fileWrapper.getFile()` outside of my inner class, it won't wait util inner class had called `setFile()`. In short, `fileWrapper.getFile()` will get nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just extract your action listener to be named inner class of Solution and you will be able to assign Solution.this.file from the inner class :

```
public class Solution extends JFrame {
   private class MyListener extends FileSelectionListener{
@Override
            protected void setSelection(File selectedFile) {
                Solution.this.file = selectedFile;  // NO compilation error here
            }
}
    private static final String FILE_NAME_1 = "Selected SOLL:";
    private File file;
    private void setNewButton(Container contentPane, final String fileName, String format, File file) {
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        final Label label = new Label("Select " + fileName + " in ." + format +" format");
        contentPane.add(label);
        contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        Button selection = new Button("Select " + fileName);
        contentPane.add(selection);
        selection.addActionListener(new MyListener() );
    }

    public uploadFiles() {
        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        setNewButton(contentPane, FILE_NAME_1, "xls", file1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it is a little bit confusing for me.

Comment: Thank you for your example.

Comment: @Aleander I think there is a small error. There is a `private File file` in Solution, but inside `uploadFiles`, you pass the `file1` which is not decleared. According to @M. Prokhorov  and @Chang 's anwser, I found if I use `private File file1` directly in `FileSelectionListener`, there will be no error. So I decide to use a switch to assign different `selectedFile` to members in `Solution`